# Execute oozie coordinator until dataset is populated

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I need to start Oozie coordinator periodically checking if data for processing is ready. Then process it once and stop executions until tomorrow.
What is the best approach to it? It seems I need a kind of anti-dataset for coordinator.

Now it starts every N minutes till the end of day and it's not a clean solution.